# sql to orm LARAVEL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

How are you? I have one question for you. How will be code in ORM Laravel this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE category LIKE 'Laptops';
```

Answer (score 0):

U should really read [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent)

It is MVC framework so assuming u have model products with category for each product u use something like

```php
Products::where('category', 'LIKE', "%Laptops%")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

> Product::where('category', 'LIKE',$variable)->get();